# iphone - Shrink image on scroll away in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface

So I have a `UIScrollView` in my app's menu. I have paging enabled and each page contains a button and an image. I would like to add a little animation where these start to shrink as they disappear off the screen (when the user scrolls to the next page).

I know I could do this by creating a property for each button and image and then manually changing the frame size in the `scrollViewDidScroll` method.

Does anyone have a more elegant solution so that I dont have to hard code each one in? It is possible that there's a predefined attribute for this or something?

Comment: If your minimum deployment target is iOS 6, you can do this fairly easily with a `UICollectionView` and a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`.  Watch [Session 205 - Introducing Collection Views from WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=205) to get started.

Comment: Thanks thats a great idea. I was hoping to allow for earlier versions though so I think I'll try another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is each "page" in the scrollview actually a view or view controller?  Whatever it is, hopefully it's an instance of some class, and thus reusable.  Add  a method to the custom view/view controller that uses the UIView animateWithDuration: methods to make the button and image shrink.  Call that method when you determine that the scroll view has moved enough.

Comment: Ive marked this correct since it pointed me in the right direction, but any chance you could flesh it out a little?